# Triple join sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I Want some specific data form my sql databank while using a query.
My first table contains all the teams for my app. (table 1)
The second table contains the relation between an other table:
This table has the fields :

- UniqueId
- TeamUniqueId (the uniqueId of table 1)

I want to have the data of the opposite of an inner join :

[image: Opposite of inner join]

```
Select * From table_1
Full outer join table_2
on table_1.UniqueId = table_2.table_1UnqiueId
Where table_1.UniqueId IS NULL
OR table_2.UniqueId IS NULL
```

So this gives the right data.

---

But now i want compare this data with table_3 ,
And i want all the data that isnt linked with the 3th table

table_3
 1. Unique ID
 2. TeamUniqueId (uniqueId from first table)

To put it in a picture
[image]

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Hmm thanks willl usse it next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might use a more brute force approach:

```
select uniqueid
from ((select uniqueid, 1 as t1, 0 as t2, 0 as t3
       from table_1
      ) union all
      (select uniqueid, 0 as t1, 1 as t2, 0 as t3
       from table_2
      ) union all
      (select uniqueid, 0 as t1, 0 as t2, 1 as t3
       from table_3
      ) 
     ) t
group by uniqueid
having (sum(t1) = 1 or  -- in table1
        sum(t2) = 1     -- or table2
       ) and
       count(*) = 1;  -- in only one table
```

In some databases you could also use set functions.  Something like this:

```
((select unique1
  from table_1
  union
  select unique1
  from table_2
 ) minus  -- or except
 (select unique1
  from table_1 t1
  intersect
  select unique1
  table_2 t2
 )
) minus  -- or except
select unique1
from table_3;
```

Comment: This didn't work, I still get the fields that are linked to table_3
I think my question is put wrongly , i'll delete this one. It's more complex than this picture, sorry for timewaste. thanks for reaction !

Comment: @TimVd . . . That should not be possible using either mechanism.

Comment: Did some more research and found the solution, your code changed my way of thinking for this problem ! Thanks